# Python 2.7 and Ubuntu 10.10: X11 fails

Tags: python, ubuntu, xorg, x-server

Against every recommendation I have `apt-get remove python` in Ubuntu 10.10 (build 2.6.24-29-server x86_64) and `apt-get install python2.7`

Some built-in software with python2.6 dependencies (like firefox, other minor stuff) was fixed  just by apt-get reinstalling or reinstalling from source and the system was stable for one day until I rebooted.

Upon booting I got the message "ubuntu is running in low-graphics mode"
I have an NVIDIA Quadro NVS 295 256 running on a HP Z600 Workstation so I sudoed:

```
apt-get --purged nvidia* 
apt-get --purged xserver
apt-get install linux-headers-generic
apt-get install nvidia-*
apt-get install xserver-xorg
dpkg-reconfigure xserver-xorg
nvidia-xconfig
```

upon rebooting i get the same "ubuntu is running in low-graphics mode"
if I decide to tell the boot menu to restart X, the Ubuntu 10.10 "load screen" shows up and does not do anything for hours.

If I "X" the screen remains black for hours; ctrl-c shows that /etc/X11/xorg.conf did not produce any errors just a warning "Type "ONE_LEVEL"...". 
/var/log/Xorg.0.log issues the following warnings (no errors)
(WW) AllowEmptyInput is on
(WW) NVIDIA(0): UBB is incompatible

If I "startX" I get /usr/bin/python: can't find '_____main_____.py"' in '/usr/share/command-not-found' Before re-installing xserver-xorg however "startX" ran, just by changing the resolution of the tty1 console.

Any hints?

Comment: This question may be better suited for superuser or askubuntu.

Comment: This question might be a better fit for http://askubuntu.com/